# M1 mac numpy problems

Tags: python, numpy, apple-m1

Using PyCharm to code in python. I set my terminal to be Rosetta simulated and installed Numpy through terminal. Now I can run my Numpy code from inside the terminal, but when I try to compile it inside PyCharm I get and error saying:

```
* The Python version is: Python3.9 from "/Users/kubab/PycharmProjects/fix/venv/bin/python"
* The NumPy version is: “1.20.3"

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/kubab/PycharmProjects/fix/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Users/kubab/PycharmProjects/fix/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
        /Users/kubab/PycharmProjects/fix/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Comment: I installed intel version of PyCharm. Now everything seems to be working, just slower due to rosetta. I wonder if the m1 version of PyCharm is just bugged or I can't manage it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use m1 version just install numpy with miniforge while in non-rosetta terminal:

```
brew install miniforge
```

(Replace 'boost' with the anything you want)

```
conda create -n boost
conda activate boost
conda install python=3.9.4
conda install numpy
```

Then select the miniforge python in M1 PyCharm.

[source](https://archive.is/0fS8a)